# Locking in multiprocessor systems

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, synchronization, locking

If two threads from different cores/cpu try to acquire a lock at the exact same time, how is it decided which thread will acquire the lock first?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how to answer this, but here are my ideas:

1. I believe that it would be very unlikely that this would happen at the **exact** same time.
2. There may be some priority assigned to each thread. The thread with the highest priority will get the lock. This priority could be explicitly kept eg an integer value, or it 
   could be some other metric (such as which thread has had more time executing, for example.)
3. Another primitive method would be to always give the lock to the thread running on the lower "cpu" number. This would be a simple tie breaker.
4. Many of the more recent locking algorithms will run in stages. Therefore, at any time, there may be n threads with a "want" for some lock. Generally, they will be queued up, possibly with some priority (as mentioned above).

I hope this helps, but as I said, I'm not certain this is correct, it's just an educated guess.

Comment: It can happen at the same time because of multi core cpu. Each thread can run in a different core and can try to acquire the lock at the exact same time.

Comment: CPU's run on a microsecond scale - It's highly unlikely that two threads will grab the same lock at some microsecond granularity.